# How to have workspaces only on secondary monitors

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, workspaces

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I have a configuration with a laptop with other 2 external monitors.

I am using workspaces and what I like to do is to hold the laptop screen (that is the primary display) while I am changing the workspace in the other two monitors.
Or even better have an independent workspace per monitor.
Is it possible to do that?